# Check if today's record already exist or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-query-store

I have a table with multiple columns where I need to check if the column **ANI** (ANI is the mobile numbers) called for their first time or they have existing record on the previous dates, I need to return like 1 if exist and 0 if not

I have tried a query but seems to be far away, any guidance will be much appreciated

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ANI) as mobile
FROM ODCalls
(CallLocalTime)  >= '2022-06-08 00:00:00'
and ANI NOT IN (
    select ANI
    from ODCalls
    WHERE (CallLocalTime)  >= '2022-06-01 00:00:00'
    and (CallLocalTime)  >= '2022-06-07 23:59:59'
)
```

Comment: Correct you syntax errors first. Then if its not working provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.ANI AS MOBILE
FROM ODCalls AS T
GROUP BY T.ANI
HAVING MIN(CAST(T.CallLocalTime AS DATE)=CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE)
```

You can try something like this. I am not completely sure with out sample data about possible issues with datetime. This query should detect mobile phones, which have made the first call today.